# Can vectors be used to create shapes?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Can vectors be used to create 3D shapes, such as a square or triangle. And are there any equations which create 3d shapes, specifially that of a cube.

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/geometry.html

Comment: vectors are indispensable or at least very important for creating shapes.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

the equation:
$$
\max \{|x_1|,|x_2|, |x_3|\}=a
$$
for $\vec x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3$ represents a cube. Do you see it?